# Not correctly closing the <sub> tag renders "correctly" in the preview zone but not in the actual text

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

If you open the `<sub>` tag and forget to close it in a question's text, it will render text as subscript in the preview zone, but not on the actual question's page.

For instance, this text renders as subscript from the preview zone.

Comment: Incorrect HTML is incorrect...

Comment: @Shog9 Of course it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have changed the preview to work more like the server-side version when handling invalid markup, so after the next build, the preview of your post will look like the final version.