# Use [wont-fix] instead of [status-bydesign] for some questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-tags

I've seen a lot of questions tagged as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) here, but when I read the question it appears that they are unfixable bugs.

Some of these features have obviously not been designed, just following badly written third-party APIs or something.

I propose that a different tag such as [wont-fix](/questions/tagged/wont-fix) or [unable-tofix](/questions/tagged/unable-tofix) should be used in conjunction with the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag.

To be honest, it comes across badly to see status by design when it's obviously not by design. Won't fix though more direct feels more honest.

---

**EDIT:** What are other people's feelings about this? Could a discussion be held?

**EDIT 2:** To try to better explain my position. 'Won't Fix' is a standard resolution in most bug-tracking systems I use.

'By design' implies that there's no problem, move along. I'm not saying that every [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) should be a [tag:won't-fix], but there are certainly a number of them that are recognized as minor problems. The existing tag used to close these implies that there is no problem.

**Examples**:

- [Links choosing sort order in 'favorites' tab of one's own user page have &amp; in URL and don't work for "open in new tab"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70348/links-choosing-sort-order-in-favorites-tab-of-ones-own-user-page-have-amp-in)
- [Not correctly closing the <sub> tag renders "correctly" in the preview zone but not in the actual text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68010/not-correctly-closing-the-sub-tag-renders-correctly-in-the-preview-zone-but-n)
- [Getting "can only post questions every 20 minutes" but did not post recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844/cant-post-question-status-incorrect)

Comment: This'll probably be closed as `status-bydesign`.

Comment: Yes I'm actually aware of that. It's a bit ironic. However its actually the valid closing tag on this.

Comment: This isn't _Meta_ Stack Overflow for nothing ;)

Comment: @Mike Caron I don't know what you mean sorry.

Comment: You're discussing the use of [status-bydesign] on Meta SO threads, in a Meta SO thread, expecting it to be closed with [status-bydesign]. That's pretty much the text-book definiton of meta.

Comment: I cannot see any reason why that additional information should be a tag.

Comment: Would `status-dont-give-a-crap` be more descriptive? ;)

Comment: @gnostradamus I think that that tag should be saved for use on questions pertaining to syntax highlighting of non-C derived languages.

Comment: This is still being voted on. I thought it was resolved. Does that mean people do want to see it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) will be used in the case you describe, when we are declining to "fix" this bug.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) is used when the behavior is more or less as intended, either by the world or us.

Comment: I don't know why I haven't seen that before. I know I've seen specific examples in the past.  Declined is fine with me.