# Hats sometimes break the alignment of `{asked|answered} <date>` text on user cards

Tags: bug, winter-bash

It's easier to explain with a picture.

- Normal behavior:

[image: ok]

- Hat is too high up, the text is misaligned:

[image: not ok]

Comment: Since hats are gone in a few hours and we probably won’t have hats next year, I don’t think that you have to be concerned about this bug :)

Comment: HolyBlackCat, it's not worth fixing a bug with less than two hours life on it, somewhat related reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70972/282094 - if the problem was causing harm it would be another matter. Thanks for reporting, it's not for a lack of interest; there's bigger fish to fry.

Comment: @Jdrupal Shame, I liked this tradition. :/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It doesn’t mean that there won’t be anything in the winter time, just not hats necessarily :)